regex capture group being empty
I'm trying to create a regex that will capture various details of a list of contact entries with the format like so:
LastName, FirstName I (Administrative)

test.test@test.com
999-999-9999 ext 1
999-999-9999
Active User

In this case, the last three lines are optional (phone #2, user status, and not confirmed). The middle initial and phone extensions are also optional.
Everything works great if phone #2 is there, but as soon as phone #2 is gone the capturing groups after it record nothing. The extensions or middle initial missing don't break the groups after so I thought a similar method would work with phone 2. What am I doing wrong?
This is the regex I created (I added lines between groups to improve readability):
([a-zA-Z-]+, [a-zA-Z-]+(?: \w)?)
 \((Technical|Administrative|CIO or Equivalent|Emergency)\)
\n\n([a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*)
\n((?:\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4})(?: ext \d{1,5})?)
\n((?:\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4})?(?: ext \d{1,5})?)
((?:\nActive User|\nInactive User|\nNever Logged In)?)
((?:\nNot Confirmed)?)


Are you doing this in a programming language?  Because this is a bonkers use case for regex.  It's complicated and extremely delicate  What you have is a simple parsing problem.  Just do it line by line.  Old saying "I had a problem.  So, I wrote a regular expression.  Now I have TWO problems."

Yeah this is in C#, The automated playwright test I was tasked to write wanted to verify the formatting matched this pattern, but you may have a good point here. I could at least do a line by line test instead of one massive regex.

When phone #2 is missing, is there a blank line in its place? Because the newline isn't optional in the regexp.

Great catch Barmar, I changed the regex to make it \n? and that solved it.

@TimRoberts, that well-worn expression implies that regular expressions have no place in a programmer's toolkit, a sentiment that is not universally shared.

It would be best, if you break it apart and validate each line separately. That being said, the regex pattern can be simplified. For instance, the email regex will fail anyway for some non-emails. You might as well simplify that.

(?im)([a-z-]+\s*,\s*[a-z-]+(?:\s*\w)?)\s*((Technical|Administrative|CIO
or
Equivalent|Emergency))\s*([^\r\n@]+@[^\r\n.]+(?:.[a-z0-9-]+)+)?\s*(\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4})?\s*(?:ext\s*(\d{1,5}))?\s*(\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4})?\s*(Active User|Inactive User|Never Logged In)?\s*(Not Confirmed)?

Example
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

void findMatch() {

    string pattern = @"(?im)([a-z-]+\s*,\s*[a-z-]+(?:\s*\w)?)\s*\((Technical|Administrative|CIO or Equivalent|Emergency)\)\s*([^\r\n@]+@[^\r\n.]+(?:\.[a-z0-9-]+)+)?\s*(\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4})?\s*(?:ext\s*(\d{1,5}))?\s*(\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4})?\s*(Active User|Inactive User|Never Logged In)?\s*(Not Confirmed)?";
    string input = @"LastName, FirstName I (Administrative)

                    test.test@test.com
                    999-999-9999 ext 1
                    999-999-9999
                    Active User
                    Not Confirmed";
    RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline;
    
    foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern, options))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at index {1}.", m.Value, m.Index);
    }

}

findMatch()

which returns:
'LastName, FirstName I (Administrative)

                    test.test@test.com
                    999-999-9999 ext 1
                    999-999-9999
                    Active User
                    Not Confirmed' found at index 0.

Note that since except the first line, all the other lines are optional, a ? is required for each statement, after the first line pattern.

(?im): Inline insensitive and multiline flags. Use multiline flag so that you don't have to count and use \n.
(): Add capture group, where necessary and use (?:) non-capture groups, if capture group is unnecessary.
\s*: Add zero or more spaces, where necessary.

